# car-like robot navigation in gazebo

Tags: gazebo, navigation, laser, urdf, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hallo.
I've got urdf car-like robot model, which i can teleoperate in gazebo. Also i've added hokuyo laser scan to it.
The question is: what are next steps to realize navigation on my robot?
What are the basic principles of implementing navigation?

Is there any useful links or tutorials?

Can i somehow modify move_base for my robot?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43091/car-like-robot-navigation-in-gazebo/) by [Peter Listov](https://answers.ros.org/users/3071/peter-listov/) on ROS Answers with karma: 338 on 2012-09-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [abdullah](https://answers.ros.org/users/1083/abdullah/) on 2012-09-10**:
Hello, Peter. I want to use car-like robot in gazebo and want to control it from keyboard. Previously I was working with differential drive robots in gazebo. Can you please guide me that how I can start working with car like robots in gazebo. Is there any tutorial? Thanks

**Comment by [Peter Listov](https://answers.ros.org/users/3071/peter-listov/) on 2012-09-10**:
Actually I have not seen any tutorials specially for car-like robots. So I did it step by step. First created my urdf-model. Then added joint controllers and implemented simple teleop-control node. Now i'm trying to make wheel-odometry for it.

**Comment by [abraham](https://answers.ros.org/users/39945/abraham/) on 2019-03-15**:
selam peter ,i was search a bit, it seems their is no tutorial to implement teleop-control for carlike robot even now , can you  please explain how you create teleop node and implement it in gazebo ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is presently no complete solution, but you may find some of the links from the [Ackermann steering group](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Ackermann%20Group) useful.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-09-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [forinkzan](https://answers.ros.org/users/20935/forinkzan/) on 2015-01-06**:
@joq what are you mean by " There is presently no complete solution " , are there no people who already done the navigation in gazebo? or even can't make wheel-odometry & differential drive robot in it ?
**PS:  i really want to know it , it's very important to me .**

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2015-01-22**:
That comment was accurate back in Sept. 2012. The situation has change since then. I no longer work on driverless cars, but others have made what appears to be significant progress. Please check the http://wiki.ros.org/Ackermann%20Group links.

**Comment by [forinkzan](https://answers.ros.org/users/20935/forinkzan/) on 2015-01-22**:
thank you , and i already can teleop and build map in gazebo~ now i want to navigation in it ~

**Comment by [gleb](https://answers.ros.org/users/27760/gleb/) on 2016-08-31**:
@forinkzan I am trying to control a car-like robot in gazebo as well. Could you please explain how you realized the teleoperation? And did you manage to navigate it?